# .innerHTML is applying to two divs when should only apply to one

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple rock, paper, scissors game in which I am looking to increase the score count by an increment of one depending on if the user or computer wins.

The problem I am facing is when I try to apply the score, for example: the user wins and the computer loses the `element.innerHTML` is changing both the user score AND computer score to 1.  I cannot not figure this out as the user `html` element and computer `html` element have different ID's and I am targeting them through these.

Any suggestions (hope the above makes sense:))

```js
let countUser = 0;
let countComp = 0;

const displayScoreUser = document.getElementById("user-score").innerHTML = countUser += 1;
const displayScoreComp = document.getElementById("computer-score").innerHTML = countComp += 1;

if (user_selection === 'rock' && computer_choice === 'scissors') {
  displayScoreUser;
  console.log(displayScoreUser);
  alert('user wins');
} else if (user_selection === 'scissors' && computer_choice === 'paper') {
  displayScoreUser;
  console.log(displayScoreUser);
  alert('user wins');
} else if (user_selection === 'paper' && computer_choice === 'rock') {
  displayScoreUser;
  console.log(displayScoreUser);
  alert('user wins');
} else if (user_selection === 'scissors' && computer_choice === 'rock') {
  displayScoreComp;
  console.log(displayScoreComp);
  alert('computer wins');
} else if (user_selection === 'rock' && computer_choice === 'paper') {
  displayScoreComp;
  console.log(displayScoreComp);
  alert('computer wins');
} else if (user_selection === 'paper' && computer_choice === 'scissors') {
  displayScoreComp;
  console.log(displayScoreComp);
  alert('computer wins');
} else {
  alert('its a draw');
}
```

```html
<div class="score-row pt-5">
  <div class="score-col item-1">
    <h3>User Score</h3>
    <div class="score-box">
      <h2 id="user-score">0</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-col item-2">
    <h2 class="display-3">You Win!!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="score-col item-3">
    <h3>Computer Score</h3>
    <div class="score-box">
      <h2 id="computer-score">0</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please complete the code so that we can see how things tie together. It is not clear when this code is executed, what these undefined variables are, where the event handlers are, ...etc.

Comment: You seem to think *displayScoreUser* is a function, it's not.

Comment: user_selection and computer_choice variables are not defined.  please complete the code. so that we can find out the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is the issue ?**

`displayScoreUser` and `displayScoreComp` are not functions they are variables(constants) , it's gonna do nothing if you retype them on your code ... also both of `user` and `computer` where getting an initial point at the start because of the values you assigned to them at the beginning .. here is how you can fix it ....just transform your `displayScoreUser` and `displayScoreComp` into functions :

**Solution :**

```
function displayScoreUser () {
 countUser++ 
 document.getElementById("user-score").innerHTML = countUser;
 };

 function displayScoreComp () {
 countComp++ 
 document.getElementById("computer-score").innerHTML = countComp;
 };
```

then you call them whenever the `user` or `computer` wins an action :

```
displayScoreUser () // when user wins
displayScoreComp () // when computer wins
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `displayScoreUser` and `displayScoreComp` to functions and call them in the conditions:

```
const displayScoreUser = () => document.getElementById("user-score").innerHTML = countUser += 1;
const displayScoreComp = () => document.getElementById("computer-score").innerHTML = countComp += 1;
```

```
if (user_selection === 'rock' && computer_choice === 'scissors') {
                displayScoreUser();
                alert('user wins');
            } 
// And so on ...
```

Answer (score -4):

I think the solution is about changing: countUser += 1; to ++countUser. Do the same with countComp variable and it should work properly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how the variable is incremented. In fact, there is no practical difference between `x += 1`  and `++x` - they would both increment the variable and return the new value. As others have pointed out, it's because OP *sets* both of these before even running the code *and* assuming that the line that sets the value in the HTML won't be executed until later.